# "Stream is sending an event before being opened"

Tags: ios, networking, swift, ios8

I'm trying to make a SOAP request with Swift. Running the latest Xcode/iOS as of 9/9/14. I use an `NSMutableURLRequest` that I add an HTTPBody to with the request info. However, Once I start an `NSURLConnection` with the request, I get an error "Stream xxxxxxxxx is sending an event before being opened". I'm not using any networking libraries, just a plain old `NSURLConnection`. Any thoughts on what could cause this error? Thanks!

Relevant code in use:

```
func createSOAPRequestWithEnvelope(soapEnvelope : String) {
    //create request
    var url = NSURL(string: "https://my-service-url")
    var req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 5000)

    req.addValue("text/xml",    forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    req.HTTPBody = soapEnvelope.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    //begin connection
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: req, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    connection.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    connection.start() //error happens after this command :(
}

//takes care of NTLM Authentication
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!) {
    var authMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod

    if authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM {
        var credential = NSURLCredential(user: self.username,
            password: self.password,
            persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)

        challenge.sender.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    }
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    // Response received, clear out data
    self.transactionData = NSMutableData()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
    // Store received data
    self.transactionData?.appendData(data)
}
```

Comment: Could you try `req.addValue("100-continue", forHTTPHeaderField:"Expect")` ?

Comment: I tried this, and it *seemed* to make the request go through, though the request is returning an error from the API `HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.` It's worth noting that before I started getting the original error posted above (approximately prior iOS 8 beta 4), the request would go through without a hitch with the same code.

Comment: This actually led me to discover the network request WAS going through (though is still spitting out the `Stream....` error every time, just not crashing) and the failure was actually occurring further down the line, so thanks!

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. I hit a similar problem - after upgrade to ios8 the  "stream not open" messsages appeared and the app froze - can you share insights of the problem "farther down the line" that you found?

Comment: It turned out the error I was getting was not relevant to the stream not open messages. They still appear, sadly, hence why I left the question open, they just weren't what was causing my app crash at all.

Comment: I'm also getting this but I don't see any negative impact. Anyone have an idea if this is a problem and/or how to mitigate it?

Comment: here same getting issue it. Any luck? iOS 8 would not working but working ios 7 and 6.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with Stream not Open seems to be directly i CFNetwork implementation. (reproducible when using NSConnection and also NSSession). It occurs for requests (responses) that needs to be chunked. A side-effect of this issue is that windows authentication is not working properly and each request needs to go through complete handshaking process. And it is not fixed also in iOS 8.1.

Comment: I face the same problem. Did you file a bug report I can copy?

Comment: I don't have a solution for it. Created bug report to Apple, but it was closed as a duplicate and I cannot see the status of primary bug. Tested today with iOS 8.2 beta and still same issue. Solution might be using AFNetworking library instead of standard Apple buggy implementation.

Comment: I tried AFNetworking and no luck on my side I'm afraid.  It's a shame, my app really counts on this SOAP request

Comment: Yes it's still there. I've also used Apple technical support and they told me they know about this issue and they are going to fix it, but they didn't tell me in which version :-)

Comment: This does not seem to be resolved in iOS 8.3 either.

Comment: Still the same issue in iOS 9 Beta.

Comment: Ok, so in iOS 9.0 Beta 3 and 4 it seems that windows authentication works fine again. I still see the "Stream is sending event ..." logs, but it looks like it doesn't affect authentication any more

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere for this problem and ultimately I was passing the wrong credentials at didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge :(

Check if you are accidentally doing the same too

If that doesn't work try this:

Embed your credentials in the url string

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://username:password@domain.com/home";
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

Comment: It was so for me too.

When you send wrong credentials from NSURLSession.didReceiveChallenge you can check NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.previousFailureCount, and if it is more than zero - cancel attempts with error: completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);