# AFNetworking 2.0 Authentication Kerberos and NTLM

Tags: authentication, ios7, kerberos, afnetworking-2, ntlm

I have a web service that is behind an NTLM authentication.  In AFNetworking 1.0 I could authenticate with the web service from my iOS app.  I am now migrating to AFNetworking 2.0 and finding it difficult to find information on AFNetworking 2.0 authentication for NTLM or Kerberos.

Are there any full examples of NTLM or Kerberos authentication available for AFNetworking 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AFNetworking NTLM Authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483465/afnetworking-ntlm-authentication)

Comment: @mattt that question you say is a duplicate is for AFNetworking 1.0 and is from 2 years ago whereas I am specifically asking about AFNetworking 2.0 (the most recent release).  This question should not be closed.

Comment: Very little has changed with respect to authentication between the two versions. It's still based on authentication challenges and NSURLCredential.

Comment: Hi @motionpotion I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 3):

It's seems NSURRSession problem. I have simple example (NSURLSession) with NTLM authentication  on windows Web services (Navision). It worked perfectly on ios7. It work in ios 8.1 on iphone5 (with bugs - see below) simulator and it do not work on iphone6/6+ simulator at all! (ios 8.2 - same). I'm watched auth process with Charlesproxy: app sends up to 3 request to authenticate. On third try it authenticate. At same time I see in xcode debug:
  "Stream xxxx is sending an event before being opened"

You can read about it: ["Stream is sending an event before being opened"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755555/stream-is-sending-an-event-before-being-opened)

So, I think your problem is not AFNetworking bug, it's Apple bug. Not fixed yet.