# Stream is sending an event before being opened Web Service error

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, sharepoint

I have an iOS app that makes calls to various SharePoint web services.  The following web services work:

GetListItems, GetCurrentUserInfo

But the one that isn't working is UpdateListItems

I get the following error when trying to call this web service:

```
Stream XXX is stending an event before being opened
```

The funny thing is, this used to work when I was building the application with an older Xcode (circa 2011 or 2012).

I've read posts on here about delaying the start of the NSURLConnection and that doesn't work, same error.  I've tried the latest version of AFNetworking and that doesn't work, same error.

The error occurs at the following line of code:

```
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];  // error: Stream is sending an event before being opened
```

or at

```
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmidiately:NO];
[theConnection performSelector@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];  // error: Stream is sending an event before being opened
```

Comment: Look at this question..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755555/stream-is-sending-an-event-before-being-opened

Comment: Ah thanks.  Looks like other people are struggling. Sadly, no one can find an answer :(

Comment: Yeah there's no solution to this issue.. I'm trying with share point server and struggling to resolve this issue.